# Extending solder only PCB pins

Tags: pcb, soldering, pins

What is the recommended way to make solid connections to the pins below?
Can the soldering be avoided, and if not, what component should be used to provide the plug/unplug connection?

[image]

Comment: You need a socket. FPC/FRC Sockets are a way to go. Google might help.

Comment: "PCB edge connector" is a common name for what you're looking for.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The picture might be a bit misleading, but I don't believe it's an edge connector. The whole board isn't supposed to be plugged into a slot

Comment: @Alan can you post a picture of the **whole** PCB?

Comment: @d3l Updated with a larger picture. It show the pins I'm referring to

Comment: Is there a corresponding row of pins on the other side of the PCB?

Comment: Also what is the spacing between pins?

Comment: @PeterGreen No pins on the other side. Spacing is between 1 and 2mm (am not able to measure correctly)

Comment: Could it be meant for a single row of SMT pin headers?

Comment: @uint128_t Given that it is for SMT, is there a proper way to extend that to enable connecting without soldering.

Comment: If you're lucky, the pitch matches a common PCB edge connector. Otherwise, you'll probably have to solder something to it, header or otherwise.

Comment: The pads are their for a purpose. So, why not ask relayr, https://www.relayr.io/wunderbar/, for example on their forum https://forum.relayr.io/ and get a definitive answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all the guys that commented. 
There seems not to be a solution that doesn't include soldering. There are some suggestions to use PCB edge connectors but those would not be a solution if the pins are located in the middle of the PCB.

The component name to use is an "smd pin header".
[Example](http://www.tracepartsonline.net/PartsDefs/Production/ASSMANN/10-21062010-071719/pictures/10-21062010-071719L.gif)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [pogo pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_pin)? ([Also here](https://www.mill-max.com/new_products/pages/spring-loaded-contacts?gclid=Cj0KEQiAtri0BRDLoaCF95e7o_sBEiQA_pgRQyipX5IFRBgeb-PAt9BU8xbluSned-8Wgcn3pnam9r4aAot48P8HAQ).)They generally require that you build a custom fixture to align and clamp the PCB to the pins.